# Display Signal Noise Ratio SNR in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have go a clean signal (manchester coding), and the same signal with an including noise -  what formula I have to use to get the Signal to Noise Ratio?

```
%manchester code
T = length(bits)/bitrate; % full time of bit sequence
n = 200;
N = n*length(bits);
dt = T/N;
t = 0:dt:T;
x = zeros(1,length(t)); % output signal

for i = 0:length(bits)-1
  if bits(i+1) == 1
    x(i*n+1:(i+0.5)*n) = 1;
    x((i+0.5)*n+1:(i+1)*n) = -1;
  else
    x(i*n+1:(i+0.5)*n) = -1;
    x((i+0.5)*n+1:(i+1)*n) = 1;
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by formula? Do you want to add noise to your signal at a certain `Eb/No` ?

Comment: I want to get the snr of my noisy signal

Comment: I have a clean_signal and a noisy_signal (inlcuding cleansignal + noise)

Comment: @Sanap then mark in your code which variable is the clean signal and which is the noisy signal?

Comment: Does [this](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/how-do-i-calculate-snr-of-noisy-signal) or [this](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35658-how-can-i-calculate-the-signal-to-noise-ratio-snr-of-a-signal) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is relatively easy to do this in Matlab and there are several approaches. Good to mention is, that there is the `snr`-function in the Signal Processing Toolbox. If you don't have it, then use the RMS-values like described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio#Definition).

An alternative for zero-mean signals is to use an approach with the standard deviation or the variance. *Important:* They do only work when the mean (expected value) is zero.

*Here the code:*

```
% random data
bits = randi(2,1,20)-1;
bitrate = 1;

% manchester code
T = length(bits)/bitrate; % full time of bit sequence
n = 200;
N = n*length(bits);
dt = T/N;
t = 0:dt:T;
x = zeros(1,length(t)); % output signal
for i = 0:length(bits)-1
  if bits(i+1) == 1
    x(i*n+1:(i+0.5)*n) = 1;
    x((i+0.5)*n+1:(i+1)*n) = -1;
  else
    x(i*n+1:(i+0.5)*n) = -1;
    x((i+0.5)*n+1:(i+1)*n) = 1;
  end
end

% add offset to test (approach with standard deviation
% and variance are NOT going to produce the correct SNR then)
%x = x + 1;

% x is the clean signal
s = x + 0.1*randn(size(x));     % noisy signal
e = s - x;                      % noise

% Matlab function in the Signal Processing Toolbox
SNR = snr(x,e)

% with RMS values
rms_x = sqrt(mean(x.^2));
rms_e = sqrt(mean(e.^2));
SNR = 10*log10((rms_x/rms_e)^2) % SNR in dB
SNR = 20*log10(rms_x/rms_e)     % SNR in dB

% with standard deviation (only for signals with zero-mean)
sigma_x = std(x);
sigma_e = std(e);
SNR = 20*log10(sigma_x/sigma_e) % SNR in dB

% with variance (only for signals with zero-mean)
var_x = var(x);
var_e = var(e);
SNR = 10*log10(var_x/var_e)     % SNR in dB
```

*This is the result:*

```
SNR =
   20.1780
SNR =
   20.1780
SNR =
   20.1780
SNR =
   20.1781
SNR =
   20.1781
```

Comment: dont we have several SNR values and not only one? because we have 20 bits, and for every bit we have a noise, so dont we have 20 snr values, each for every bit?

Comment: To calculate the SNR we need a signal. If you want, you can calculate the SNR for each bit by reducing the length of the signal and it's noise to that single bit and iterate over all the bits. As far as I know, this is not done in the field.